# How to setup launchd for telegraf on macos catalina

Tags: macos, macos-catalina, launchd, telegraf

I am looking to use launchd to run telegraf in the background on my mac. I am using a custom telegraf binary which cannot be installed via homebrew. So telegraf itself is setup and working. I have created a telegraf.plist file with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>telegraf</string>
        <key>ServiceDescription</key>
        <string>Telegraf Binary</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>             
            <string>/usr/local/bin/telegraf/telegraf.conf</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

I am not sure if the string to run telegraf should point to /usr/local/bin/telegraf/telegraf.cong. This is because, in terminal, I get it running ( and also see the events ) by :

```
sudo ./telegraf --config telegraf.conf
```

What should the correct value for the string value in the array be?

Answer (score 0):

The `ProgramArguments` array should contain the path to the program to run, followed by the arguments to pass to it (one per array element). So maybe something like this (assuming the program itself is at /usr/local/bin/telegraf/telegraf):

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>             
    <string>/usr/local/bin/telegraf/telegraf</string>
    <string>--config</string>
    <string>/usr/local/bin/telegraf/telegraf.conf</string>
</array>
```

If telegraf has any other dependencies on your environment (e.g. does it require the working directory to be /usr/local/bin/telegraf? Any environment variables needed?), you may need to add to the .plist to configure those correctly.

Comment: hello Gordon - this seems to work. however  after a system reboot, I still have to manually run the following terminal commands below to get the telegraf service to start. I assumed thats what lauchd was supposed to do ?:
```
 - cd /Library/LaunchDaemons/
- sudo launchctl load  telegraf.plist
- sudo launchctl start telegraf
```

this persists only if I am still logged in. A reboot stops the telegraf service. Any ideas?

Comment: @user2022284 It might be running too early in the startup process, and crashing out. I'd recommend capturing its output and error streams by adding the `StandardOutPath` and `StandardErrorPath` keys, pointing to appropriate log locations. You might also add `<key>KeepAlive</key><true/>`, to have launchd restart it if it does crash.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my script worked on macOS Mojave. The missing step to run my script on macOS Catalina 10.15.3 via `launchd` was:

<kbd>System Preferences</kbd> > <kbd>Security & Privacy</kbd> > <kbd>Privacy</kbd> > <kbd>Full Disk Access</kbd> > <kbd>Terminal</kbd> > toggle it on